# Vue multi select limit option count

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue application that uses [multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-multiple-select), I want to have it so there are 5 options (a,b,c,d,e) and a user can select up to a max of 3. I checked the docs and this doesn't seem to be a supported param since the limit it mentions just limits how many are visable after selecting.

Here is my current code but it doesn't do what I want

Data:

```
selectedOptions: [],
optionsLimit: 3,
optionsList: ["a","b","c","d","e",]
```

Template:

```
<multiselect v-model="selectedOptions" :multiple="true" :options="optionsList" :hide-selected="true"></multiselect>
```

Current behaviour:

Will allow selecting of all 5 options instead of limiting to 3.

How can I make it so a user can select a max of 3 options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `max` prop for this: [image: a snapshot from vue-multiselect docs]

Template:

```js
<multiselect v-model="selectedOptions" :multiple="true" :options="optionsList" :hide-selected="true" :max="3"></multiselect>
```

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I missed that one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the disable feature to disable multiselect using `:disabled="selectedOptions.length>=optionsLimit"`. The code below:

```js
// register globally
Vue.component('multiselect', window.VueMultiselect.default)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedOptions: [],
    optionsLimit: 3,
    optionsList: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", ]
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">

<div id="app">

  <multiselect v-model=selectedOptions :multiple="true" :options="optionsList" :hide-selected="true" :disabled="selectedOptions.length>=optionsLimit"></multiselect>

</div>
```